# The cost of checking the connection when using JdbcPooledConnectionSource

Tags: java, jdbc, database-connection, ormlite

There is possible to let Ormlite check the connection before it will be handed over to the user when using JdbcPooledConnectionSource like this:

```
JdbcPooledConnectionSource connectionSource =
     new JdbcPooledConnectionSource("jdbc:h2:mem:account");
connectionSource.setTestBeforeGet(true);
```

What is the performance cost to let Ormlite do the checking? Why would I not let the Ormlite check the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the performance cost to let Ormlite do the checking?

You can take a look at the source for the `JdbcPooledConnectionSource`.  In the `testConnection(...)` method it effectively does:

```
connMetaData.connection.queryForLong(`SELECT 1`);
```

As to what the performance is, that would depend on a number of factors.  This is doing a RPC with your database server but should not be hitting any disk on the server.  So on a modern system we are probably talking about 10s of milliseconds – maybe less.

I think the best way to evaluate the cost of this is to turn it on and test your application and then turn it off and see if you notice a difference.

> Why would I not let the Ormlite check the connection?

The reason why the setting is there is to protect against a pooled connection failing right when you go to use it.  I would say that using it is conservative.

The `JdbcPooledConnectionSource` gives you other ways to verify the connection that aren't *every* time you go to get a pooled one.  For example, if you call `setCheckConnectionsEveryMillis(...)` to some non-0 value, it will fork a thread to test the connections every so often.  `60000` will have the thread do the `SELECT 1` in the background which should not slow your application down.